# asp.net inline tags inside user control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to create something almost similar to this [1]: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2007/09/17/inline-script-inside-an-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel.aspx

The problem I ran into is that if I use an inline tag, the page property ClientID it's resolved as "__Page" although this doesn't happen with child controls of that page. So for example if I use the control like this

```
  <tag:InlineScript runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          alert('<%= ClientID %>');
          alert('<%= SomeLabelInTheSamePage.ClientID %>');
        </script>
  </tag:InlineScript>
```

the page is rendered as:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert('__Page');
      alert('MainContent_CorrectLabelId');
    </script>
```

Any idea why?

[1] the diference is that I'm using a user control (instead of  server control) decorated with ParseChildren(false), same code as the page I linked.

Comment: are you sure that you are doing the Binding properly to return the ClientID where in the code behind if necessary are you assigning or declaring the ClientID also is ClientID stored in a Session["ClientID"] within your code..? if you are trying to follow the example .. I don't see where you are registering ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, "alert('hi')", true); as in the Url example..

Comment: What other scenarios does alert('<%= ClientID %>'); render the correct ID?  only in user controls?

Comment: you have Tag:InLineScript, have you tried to do anything like var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName("yourTagName")

Comment: Isn't it just because ClientID on its own is picking up the base ClientID - this.ClientId - i.e. Page.ClientID? And when you call it in a user control, it's picking up this.ClientId - control.ClientId = the controls client id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tag:InlineScript id="myInlineScript" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('<%=myInlineScript.ClientID %>');
        alert('<%=SomeLabelInTheSamePage.ClientID %>');
    </script>
</tag:InlineScript>
```

Comment: That should work - just calling ClientID will pull the this.ClientID which will be Page.ClientId, Control.ClientId and so on...

Comment: Ha, how did I missed that?. Thanks everyone.